# Files on github.io don't update, even after two days and after cleaning the cache

Tags: github-pages, lit-element, lit-html

Two days ago, I updated the code of my site https://danipani.github.io/,
the index file (index.html) has changed, but other files like https://danipani.github.io/node_modules/@bit/danipani.projects.global.button-3d/index.js don't update. I tried to remove the repository but no luck, everything is like before.

This is my repository:

- https://github.com/DaniPani/danipani.github.io
- this is the source code not bundled: https://github.com/DaniPani/danipani.github.io-not-bundled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your `.gitignore` file. You might have `node_modules` in there.
2. Also, you might wanna see this: https://blog.github.com/2016-11-02-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3/ . & https://blog.github.com/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/ .

Comment: There is not .gitignore file and at this link (https://github.com/DaniPani/danipani.github.io/blob/master/node_modules/%40bit/danipani.projects.global.button-3d/index.js) the file exists, but at the github.io (https://danipani.github.io/node_modules/@bit/danipani.projects.global.button-3d/index.js) not

Comment: @DaniPanidanipani Also, did you check which branch you are building from in your github pages setting?

Comment: master and it is the only branch that I have

Comment: Perfect, I added a .nojekyll file and now everything works fine. Thank you